# Polymer: Wrap <paper-item> in own element

Tags: html, polymer

I want to create my own `<menu-item>` element to remove some boilerplate code. I wrapped `<paper-icon-item>` in my own element in the following way:

```
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-item/paper-icon-item.html">

<dom-module id="menu-item">
  <template>
    <paper-icon-item>
      <iron-icon icon="[[icon]]" item-icon></iron-icon>
      <content></content>
    </paper-icon-item>
  </template>
</dom-module>

<script>
  Polymer({
    is: "menu-item",
    properties: {
      icon: { type: String }
    }
  });
</script>
```

The problem when using my `<menu-item>` is, however, that it behaves differently as to writing the template code directly in the HTML file. I suspect that the item is missing some interaction capabilities with the menu to function properly, but I can't figure it out. I tried using behaviors `Polymer.IronControlState` and `Polymer.IronButtonState` just like the paper item does, but no luck.

What am I missing to make my `<menu-item>` behave like a regular `<paper-item>`?

Comment: You probably need to use the  `Polymer.PaperItemBehavior`

Comment: Tried it with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer**

Following code is largely copied from the `paper-icon-item.html`.

```
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-behaviors/iron-control-state.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-behaviors/iron-button-state.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-flex-layout/iron-flex-layout.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-styles/typography.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-styles/color.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-styles/default-theme.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-item/paper-item-behavior.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-item/paper-item-shared-styles.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-icon/iron-icon.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-icons/iron-icons.html">

<dom-module id="menu-item">
  <template>
    <style include="paper-item-shared-styles"></style>
    <style>
      :host {
        @apply(--layout-horizontal);
        @apply(--layout-center);
        @apply(--paper-font-subhead);

        @apply(--paper-item);
        @apply(--paper-icon-item);
      }

      .content-icon {
        width: var(--paper-item-icon-width, 56px);
        @apply(--layout-horizontal);
        @apply(--layout-center);
      }
    </style>

    <div id="contentIcon" class="content-icon">
      <iron-icon icon="{{ico}}" item-icon></iron-icon>
    </div>
    <content></content>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'menu-item',

      properties: {
        ico: {
          type: String,
          value: "icons:stars"
        }
      },

      behaviors: [
        Polymer.PaperItemBehavior
      ]
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

**On Extending Elements**

I think the simplest way of changing the template of an element is by just copying it, modifying the template and its name. This approach is not without problems, it becomes very difficult to keep the new element up to date with changes in the original one. I am really craving for a better solution!.

**On Using Behaviors**

You should try to avoid consuming both an element and a behavior used by that element at the same time, you might get into trouble. For example the reason your `menu-item` doesn't look proper is because the `paper-item` inside it doesn't acquire the attribute `focused`. The `paper-item` doesn't acquire that particular attribute is because its parent element `menu-item` has the focus, `menu-item` has the focus because both `menu-item` and `paper-item` have `tabindex="0"` set on them. Why do both these elements have it set on them?, it is because of `Polymer.IronControlStateBehavior` in both of them.

Comment: Copying the code for `<paper-icon-item>` is basically what I ended up doing, and yes, it works, but it is still unsatisfactory. (And honestly, I don't know why it works.) Thanks for the reply, but I guess it doesn't really answer the question. +1 for the explanation that the focused attribute doesn't get propagated. I assume this can be solved with handlers? I will have to experiment with it.

Comment: You're right, it doesn't address the question of properly wrapping an element but I don't think there is a satisfactory answer to it, at least as of now. About the focus attribute, you could use a handler, but then again you might run into some other issues. It just feels messy.